# Any difference between recoverable databases and restorable dropped servers?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-rest-api

I was looking at Azure's REST API docs and I couldn't find any major differences between the two, as both refer to databases which can be "brought back to life" after some sort of failure or deletion of the databases.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/restorabledroppeddatabases/get
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/recoverabledatabases/get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can find in these two documents:

**Restorable Dropped Databases**:

> Gets a deleted database that can be restored.

**Recoverable Databases**:

> Gets a recoverable database, which is a resource representing a database's geo backup.

You should know the difference between restoreable and recoverable.

Restoreable is for database,  recoverable is for database backup.

Hope this helps.